# Is using nested try-except blocks problematic?

Tags: algorithms, python, exceptions

I've been seeing a lot of this construct throughout my application:

```
def doSomething():

    try:
        # setup some variables

        try:
            # do something that could throw an OSError
        except OSError as err:
            # log and handle it

        # do some more things

        try:
            # do something that could throw ValuError
        except ValueError as err:
            # log and handle it

    except Exception as err:
        # log the unexpected error

    finally:
        # close the logger
```

However, there are a number of posts that say nesting try-except blocks should be avoided, but I view that in this case:

```
try:
    # throw
except:
    try:
        # throw
    except:
        try:
            # throw
        except:
            ...
```

In my former example, the entire method body is wrapped in a single try-except to ensure that in the event an unexpected error is encountered, it's not fatal and is logged before cleanup. Further, in the outermost try-catch, the nested blocks are handled and I continue on; I therefore fail to see how I would replace that with functions.

Comment: Currently, the most comprehensive answers for this type of questions are gathered in this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/118788/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is using nested try-catch blocks an anti-pattern?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118788/is-using-nested-try-catch-blocks-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you're falling into "catch obsession", trying to catch every exception as soon as it arises.

That's not what exceptions are meant for.

Exceptions are meant to signal to a caller that some function call failed (did not fulfill its contract). So, if a function returns normally, we rely on the fact that it completed its job.

Typically, in case of failure the caller cannot fulfill its contract, and so on, up to some top-level place where the program can continue with the next action, even after the failure of the previous one.

Catch an exception only if you know a way how to turn the failure of the called function into success of the caller function. Otherwise, let the exception just ripple through to your caller.

Coming back to your code snippet:

Do you think you can still successfully complete `doSomething()` if an `OSError` happened in that code block? If not (and that typically is the answer to these questions), you must inform the caller of `doSomething()` about its failure, and as `doSomething()` can't succeed anyway, there's no point in executing the rest of the function.

So, wrapping the piece of code in `try / except OSError` is probably wrong:

- It lets the rest of the function pointlessly execute (and maybe even produce persistent nonsense).
- It doesn't inform the caller about the failure of `doSomething()`.

Answer (score 2):

Nested try-except blocks can make the code harder to understand, especially if, as in the example you used, the normal flow continues after handling the first nested try-except block.

If there is any reason that a reviewer or maintainer (or you in 6 months time) could think that the `# do some more things` from your example should belong to the handling of the `OSError`, then it might be good to seriously look at refactoring your code such that this misunderstanding can be prevented. But other than that I see no reason to refactor your code to avoid having nested try-except blocks within a single function.

---

One statement that does cause me some concern is

> In my former example, the entire method body is wrapped in a single try-except to ensure that in the event an unexpected error is encountered, it's not fatal and is logged before cleanup.

Exceptions are meant to be fatal if you don't know how to handle them. And just logging that an exception occurred is *not* handling the exception. Handling an exception is bringing your application back into a state where it can resume normal operation. If that is not possible, it is better to let the users know in a way that can not be ignored rather than logging it to a logfile that is largely ignored and trying to slog on in a broken state.

Comment: I shouldve elaborated more. When an unexpected error takes place, its logged *and* a dialog message pops up and notifies the user.